# Какой алгоритм хеширования лучше Pbkdf2 / Scrypt / bcrypt для проекта на ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, безопасность, хеширование

Не могу определиться какой алгоритм хеширования лучше использовать для проекта на ASP.NET Core для максимальной безопастности . Из чего исходить и на что опираться при выборе алгоритма . Интересуют реализации именно в рамках C# и ASP.NET Core . Так как читал , что например для .NET есть оффициальный Nuget Pbkdf2 , но при этом нет  Scrypt / bcrypt и это якобы одно из примуществ Pbkdf2 именно в приделах ASP.NET Core

Comment: Да любой. Но если хочется экзотики, то вот есть [такой стандарт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1270615/373567). Можете его доработать под себя, MD5 например на SHA256 поменять и вообще никто никогда не догадается, что это за хэш. :) По поводу всяких модных алгоритмов криптографии - загляните в NuGet пакет BouncyCastle.

Comment: Берите стандартный Pbkdf2 через Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing